# Tarjan's algorithm in graph theory

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, tarjans-algorithm

I was learning Tarjan's algorithms differently for each to find strongly connected components, to find articulation points and to find bridges in a graph. All uses the concept of finding discovery time and low-link value using dfs and dfs tree.

Logically, one would think using one algorithm's discovery time and low-link value results, we may not recompute in the other 2 algorithms and reuse them.

Am I right or are these values calculated specifically based on the underlying algorithm?